# Magento 2.3.1 Blank page after installing sample data

Tags: magento

Magento has a Blank page after installing sampledata:deploy & upgrade

I tried increasing and change php memory_limit and cleared cache and session

This is the error from magento root index.php

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Can't create directory /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/. Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only. in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:135 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\Framewo...') #1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\Framewo...') #2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\Framewo...') #3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/Class in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php on line 135

I was looking on xml and core file, would it be the layout issue? I would like that to be showing dummy sample product, but I'm ending up with a blank page.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your root directory and fire below command.
There is just issue with folder permission.

sudo chmod -R 777 generated/*

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 *
```

in the htdocs/your-magento-folder

Answer (score 0):

Permissions on the folders, and depending on magento version and your storeview (default country/language) use the -f (force) function and use the country code specified in the delpoy comment.

I have three storeviews so I use the command:
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy **-f** nl_NL de_DE en_US